# Auto increment numeric key values in a perl hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a perl script in which I am reading files from a given directory, and then placing those files into an array. I then want to be able to move those array elements into a perl hash, with the array elements being the hash value, and automatically assigning numeric keys to each hash value.

Here's the code:

```
    # Open the current users directory and get all the builds. If you can open the dir
    # then die.
    opendir(D, "$userBuildLocation") || die "Can't opedir $userBuildLocation: $!\n";
    # Put build files into an array.
    my @builds = readdir(D);
    closedir(D);
    print join("\n", @builds, "\n");
```

This print out:

```
    test.dlp
    test1.dlp
```

I want to take those value and insert them into a hash that looks just like this:

```
my %hash (
            1 => test.dlp
            2 => test1.dlp
         );
```

I want the numbered keys to be auto incrementing based on how many files I may find in a given directory.

I'm just not sure how to get the auto-incrementing keys to be set to unique numeric values for each item in the hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the need, but this should do

```
my $i = 0;
my %hash = map { ++$i => $_ } @builds;
```

another way to do it

```
my $i = 0;
for( @builds ) {
  $hash{++$i} = $_;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward and boring way:

```
my %hash;
for (my $i=0; $i<@builds; ++$i) {
  $hash{$i+1} = $builds[$i];
}
```

or if you prefer:

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#builds) {
  $hash{$i+1} = $builds[$i];
}
```

I like this approach:

```
@hash{1..@builds} = @builds;
```

Comment: This one is neater :]

Answer (score 2):

Another:

```
my %hash = map { $_+1, $builds[$_] } 0..$#builds;
```

or:

```
my %hash = map { $_, $builds[$_-1] } 1..@builds;
```